# oracle creating cubes in parallel

Tags: oracle, olap-cube

Is there a way to run two cube builds in parallel:

For instance i have the following two cube builds running sequentially:

```
 BEGIN
    DBMS_CUBE.BUILD(
      'OLAPTRAIN."TIME", OLAPTRAIN.CHANNEL, OLAPTRAIN.PRODUCT, OLAPTRAIN.GEOGRAPHY, OLAPTRAIN.SALES_CUBE',
      'CCCCC', -- refresh method
      false, -- refresh after errors
      1, -- parallelism
      false, -- atomic refresh 
      false, -- automatic order
      false); -- add dimensions
  END;



BEGIN
    DBMS_CUBE.BUILD(
      '
    OLAPTRAIN.FORECAST USING 
    (
      EXECUTE OLAP DML ''do_forecast''
    )',
      'C', -- refresh method
      false, -- refresh after errors
      1, -- parallelism
      false, -- atomic refresh 
      false, -- automatic order
      false); -- add dimensions

  END;
```

However I would like these to be build in a parallel fashion. One build taking one CPU respectively.

Can that be achieved in Analytic Workspace? If not how can I do that in PL/SQL code?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

DBMS_Scheduler might be what you're looking for.

If this is part of a regular job, then create a scheduler chain that executes both of these procedure in parallel.

You might investigate using the SCHEDULER_JOB parameter to run the build as its own job, but typically you would then have to write your own monitoring code to wait until both jobs have finished, which a scheduler chain would handle for you.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/scheduse009.htm#ADMIN10021

By the way your code would be more robust as:

```
BEGIN
  DBMS_CUBE.BUILD(
    script               => 'OLAPTRAIN."TIME", OLAPTRAIN.CHANNEL, OLAPTRAIN.PRODUCT, OLAPTRAIN.GEOGRAPHY, OLAPTRAIN.SALES_CUBE',
    method               => 'CCCCC',
    refresh_after_errors => false,
    parallelism          => 1,
    atomic_refresh       => false, 
    automatic_order      => false,
    add_dimensions       => false);
END;
```

Comment: Will they run on different CPUs is there a way to check that?

Comment: They'll run as different processes entirely. The processes have names of the form cjqNNN, so cjq002 ... cjq015 etc.  http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14231/schedadmin.htm